# UITabBarItem Image Inset issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am using `UITabBarController` , i am setting `UITabBarItem`  imageInset .

[image]

But when is am selecting same , Tab Again and again , the image size in increasing .

see here :

[Tab Bar issue video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DtT2Mwyl0sjSOzjh-tsVIu5JMmBZ1bis/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Have anyone faced this issue , please help

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late but for anyone reading this you have to balance out the insets. For example, I have a top inset of 3. I need to add -3 to the bottom inset so it doesn't move.

`nav.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 0, bottom: -3, right: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use all four insets (top,left,bottom,right) 
First of all make all four insets to 0, it will solve your problem and after that tell me why you are using insets?

Comment: I want to increase the icons size ,  how can i increase icons size  on tab TabItem , i don't have Text on it

Comment: Use a larger size image, never ever try to achieve that by using insets.